# Trello - Force Notifications (without subscribing)

Tags: trello, notifications

I need to force notifications for everyone in a board, so if someone does something everyone knows about it (through their apps and emails), that seems to be a very basic idea for a project management tool. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way subscribe another person to a card, list, or board. Adding them to a card will automatically subscribe them. Alternatively, you can mention them (using "@username") in a comment to get their attention.